# Execute multiple values to variable in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add multiple value to a parameter of a SQL Server stored procedure.

The name of the stored procedure is `gpCompRes`, parameter is `@ProgramID`

I need to add 200 + integers to `ProgramID` and I tried something like this

```
CREATE TYPE Programs as TABLE (Programs INT)
GO

DECLARE @ProgramID Programs INT

INSERT INTO @ProgramId  
VALUES (12071), (66306)

EXEC gpCompRes @ProgramId = Programs, 
               @OrganisationId = 1122,
               @UserIdList = 3326,
               @ActionUserId = 2255;
GO
```

I tried another option from the other stack flow which is also not working in my case to just declare and insert values but it did not work.

Thanks

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What error did you get?

Comment: Is it purely because you have `Declare @ProgramID Programs INT`? You have 2 datatypes there. `Programs` and `int`. Remove the `INT`: `Declare @ProgramID Programs;`

Comment: It gives me an error 

Msg 219, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The type 'Programs' already exists, or you do not have permission to create it.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'INT'.
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
Must declare the table variable "@ProgramId".

Comment: Well, if the `TYPE` Programs` already exists, you can't `CREATE` it, @Preki , that much is obvious. Considering that the Stored procedure `gpCompRes` will already have `Programs` as the datatype for the parameter `@ProgramID` then then would suggest it does already exist. And then, for the latter, as I said, you have`Progams INT`; the `INT` shouldn't be there. Seems like a typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

Programs is a user define table type.
Below the correct script.

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS Programs
GO — From SQL 2016

CREATE TYPE Programs 
AS TABLE (Program INT)
GO

DECLARE @ProgramIDs Programs — You must define @ProgramIDs variable as “Programs” type

INSERT INTO @ProgramIDs
VALUES (12071), (66306)

EXEC gpCompRes 
           @ProgramId = @ProgramIDs,
           @OrganisationId = 1122,
           @UserIdList = 3326,
           @ActionUserId = 2255
GO
```

If you will use it in a program I advise you to add a PRIMARY KEY and NOT NULL CONSTRAINT in TABLE TYPE definition in order to avoid duplicates and NULL values.

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS Programs
GO

CREATE TYPE Programs AS TABLE (Program INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
GO
```

For high-performance applications you can also convert it in IN-MEMORY TABLE TYPE as below:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS Programs
GO

CREATE TYPE Programs AS TABLE (Program INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON ) -From SQL Server 2014
```

Documentation:

[TABLE TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[MEMORY OPTIMIZED TABLE TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/memory-optimized-table-variables?view=sql-server-2014)

Comment: that worked with some additional error messages 
Msg 219, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The type 'Programs' already exists, or you do not have permission to create it.

(2 rows affected)
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure gpCompRes, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
But I will take a look.Maybe it should be the best to drop this table at the end

Comment: Try again please